# Why do Strings.Asc('š') and Strings.AscW('š') return different values?

Tags: c#, .net-standard

```
Strings.Asc('š') = 154
Strings.AscW('š') = 353
```

I'm porting an old solution to netstandard from netframework. Strings.Asc doesn't existing in the visual basic package, the only option being Strings.AscW. On the surface they appear to be a functionally the same, however they  return different solutions

Why?
I'd like the same  result  (154) from Strings.AscW, is there a similar solution that will work on .netstandard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m guessing you’ll have to go the long route via an explicit encoding, and constructing a `char` array, since there does not seem to be a method for decoding individual `char`s.

```
int result = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes(new char[] {'š'})[0];
```

Comment: Maybe also add the `[0]` and `int` cast in your answer

Comment: @Julian I explicitly didn’t do this because some encodings return more than a single byte but, fair enough, Windows-1252 never will, so it’s safe and I’ve added it now.

Comment: @KwackMaster `AscW` does work (and is generally what you *should* use, unless there’s a good reason against it), it just doesn’t do what you think it does: `AscW` returns the numeric *Unicode code point* of a given character. You should very rarely bother with anything except Unicode, and finding a character code in a legacy encoding is rarely useful.